# I need help creating two radio buttons in a View Controller using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, radio-button, viewcontroller

[code for radio buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYguC.png) I'm currently developing an iOS app in Swift using Xcode and I was tasked with creating two radio buttons which would have an effect on a total value. The first radio button needs to return a value which would be rounded to the nearest whole number OR half number (.5), the second radio button will ONLY round up or down to nearest whole number. I already have the UI radio buttons created in the View Controller (for my Settings screen). The hope is to get the total value in my app to become affected based on the corresponding radio button that is selected. I need help making that functional.

Here are the rules I was given for rounding:

**Radio Button #1:**

- 0.0 to 0.24 (Round Down to zero)
- 0.25 to 0.49 (Round Up to 0.5)
- 0.5 to 0.74 (Round Down to 0.5)
- 0.75 to 0.99 (Round Up to nearest Whole Number)

**Radio Button #2:**

- 0.00 to 0.49 (Round Down to zero)
- 0.50 to 0.99 (Round Up to nearest Whole Number)

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Since a "radio button" is *not* a native iOS class, please, include more details. (Radio buttons are most similar in iOS to a `UISegmentedControl`, as there are a single-state either/or kind of thing.) My problem with your question? Each of your radio buttons have ranges. So yeah, please, more details.

Comment: Let me explain, in case you don't know what I'm saying. *"The first radio button needs to return a value which would be rounded to the nearest whole number OR half number (.5)...."* A **button** - be it segmented, normal, or anything else - has a singular "state"... pressed, highlighted, normal, whatever. This includes "radio buttons". No button I know of... and I have nearly 40 years coding and 25 coding GUI/ui no matter the platform.... has the capabilities of "simply" rounding an undefined number. (And you haven't given any code so yes, it's totally undefined.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Just added a link to an image of the code, hope this helps.

Comment: Always add code, error messages, etc as text - so they're searchable, and can be copied when writing an answer. Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

There are two functions according to your requirement. In you original code, it presents a case same as roundHalf function.

If my understanding is right, your value should be limited to 0<=x<=1. So I add guard function to guarantee this.

Since it's a radio button, only one button can be chosen each time. So please disable the other one.

```
@IBOutlet var unitPenRadioButton1 :   UIButton!
@IBOutlet var unitPenRadioButton2 :   UIButton!

func calculateInsulin(carbs: Double, bloodSugar : Double, icRatio: Double, correctionFactor: Double)-> Double{
    do{
    let carbResult = Double(carbs / icRatio)

    var bloodResult: Double = 0

    if bloodSugar - 150 > 1{
        bloodResult = (bloodSugar - 150) / correctionFactor
    }
    let wholeBloodResult = Double(Int (bloodResult))

    let fractionBloodResult = bloodResult - wholeBloodResult

    var roundedFaction : Double

    roundedFaction = unitPenRadioButton1.isSelected  ?  try roundHalf( fractionBloodResult) : try roundWhole(fractionBloodResult)

    let finalBloodResult = wholeBloodResult + roundedFaction

    let insulinResult  = carbResult + finalBloodResult

         return insulinResult
    }
    catch let error as NSError{
        print (error)
    }

    return Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude
}




private func roundHalf(_ value : Double ) throws ->  Double{
    guard  value >= 0 && value <= 1 else {
    throw NSError.init(domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain, code: 60010, userInfo: ["error" : "value is not within [0,1]"])
    }
    return  round(value * 2.0) / 2.0
}
private func roundWhole(_ value : Double )throws ->  Double{
    guard  value >= 0 && value <= 1 else {
    throw NSError.init(domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain, code: 60010, userInfo: ["error" : "value is not within [0,1]"])
    }
    return  round(value)
}

@IBAction func didTapHalfUnit (_ sender : Any){
    unitPenRadioButton2.isSelected = false
    unitPenRadioButton1.isSelected = true
    print( calculateInsulin(carbs: 100, bloodSugar: 170, icRatio: 600, correctionFactor: 45) )
}

@IBAction func didTapWholfUnit (_ sender : Any){
    unitPenRadioButton1.isSelected = false
    unitPenRadioButton2.isSelected = true
    print( calculateInsulin(carbs: 100, bloodSugar: 170, icRatio: 600, correctionFactor:45) )
}
```

Comment: It's helpful if you add some details and context to your answer. This appears to be some rounding code the original poster (OP) might be able to use. If so, you might add more detail to help them understand how it works or why they would use it. They might also need some help with how to connect this code to their radio buttons, say, so you could give some information about that, too...

Comment: Whoever gives a negative , tells us the reason. I update my answer according to his code.

Comment: I didn't give you the downvote, E.Coms; but I'm pretty sure of the reason. On StackOverflow, your answer could be read by people all over the world, and years in the future. You need to provide more than just code. Give an explanation of *how or why* that code answers the question. You added more code to your answer - and it may very well be a solution - but you still haven't told us how or why it would help with the OP's issue.

Comment: No problem. I add some comments